# Does a lot of writing/inserting affect database indexes?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, database-design

Does a database have to rebuild its indexes every time a new row is inserted?

And by that token, wouldn't it mean if I was inserting alot, the index would be being rebuilt constantly and therefore less effective/useless for querying?

I'm trying to understand some of this database theory for better database design.

Comment: Inserting a row into an index is quite different from rebuilding the index.

Answer (score 2):

Updates definitely don't require rebuilding the entire index every time you update it (likewise insert and delete).

There's a little bit of overhead to updating entries in an index, but it's reasonably low cost. Most indexes are stored internally as a [B+Tree data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree). This data structure was chosen because it allows easy modification.

MySQL also has a further optimization called the [Change Buffer](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-insert-buffering.html). This buffer helps reduce the performance cost of updating indexes by caching changes. That is, you do an INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE that affects an index, and the type of change is recorded in the Change Buffer. The next time you read that index with a query, MySQL reads the Change Buffer as a kind of supplement to the full index.

A good analogy for this might be a published document that periodically publishes "errata" so you need to read both the document and the errata together to understand the current state of the document.

Eventually, the entries in the Change Buffer are gradually merged into the index. This is analogous to the errata being edited into the document for the next time the document is reprinted.

The Change Buffer is used only for secondary indexes. It doesn't do anything for primary key or unique key indexes. Updates to unique indexes can't be deferred, but they still use the B+Tree so they're not so costly.

If you do [OPTIMIZE TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimize-table.html) or some types of [ALTER TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html) changes that can't be done in-place, MySQL does rebuild the indexes from scratch. This can be useful to defragment an index after you delete a lot of the table, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, inserting affects them, but it's not as bad as you seem to think.  Like most entities in relational databases, indexes are usually created and maintained with an extra amount of space to accommodate for growth, and usually set up to increase that extra amount **automatically** when index space is nearly exhausted.

Rebuilding the index starts from scratch, and is different from adding entries to the index.  Inserting a new row does **not** result in the rebuild of an index.  The new entry gets added in the extra space mentioned above, except for clustered indexes which operate a little differently.

Most DB administrators also do a task called "updating statistics," which updates an internal set of statistics used by the query planner to come up with good query strategies.  That task, performed as part of maintenance, also helps keep the query optimizer "in tune" with the current state of indexes.

There are enormous numbers of high-quality references on how databases work, both independent sites and those of the publishers of major databases.  You literally can make a career out of becoming a database expert.  But don't worry too much about your inserts causing troubles. ;)  If in doubt, speak to your DBA if you have one.

Does that help address your concerns?